# cvCreateMemStorage() not working in second object instance

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a class for a detection app (one method of which initialises the necessary buffers). The class is dynamically created and the init and run method is called when a button is pressed. It runs fine.

However, if I finish the detection and return to the GUI and try to press the button again to create a new detection class and run it again, the app crashes.

It gets stuck at a call to cvCreateMemStorage(). The problem is illustrated here:

[problem http://img573.imageshack.us/img573/9498/problemp.jpg](http://img573.imageshack.us/img573/9498/problemp.jpg)
*1st time, runs fine. 2nd time, problem!*

First time around, the modelStorage gets initialised correctly. The second time around, it does not. I would have though that when the detection class is finished, all storage on the heap would be removed and I would be free to make the call to cvCreateMemStorage() in a new class?

I've also tried freeing up the modelStorage memory when finished by putting cvReleaseMemStorage( &modelStorage ); in the classes destructor BUT no joy. It is like the memory is not being de-allocated correctly.

So, beautiful denizens of stackoverflow, any ideas? :(

Comment: are these two calls in the same instance of the program? and please can you post the actual code too?

Comment: Do you release the reserved memory with `cvReleaseMemStorage()`? Consider reviwing my other answer on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951292/how-do-you-delete-a-cvseq-in-opencv/5951374#5951374

Comment: @karlphillip, afraid not. Hit a roadblock. Like I said though, I've also tried freeing up the modelStorage memory when finished by putting cvReleaseMemStorage( &modelStorage ); in the classes destructor BUT no joy. It is like the memory is not being de-allocated correctly.

Comment: With no source code it's impossible to help you any further.